# How to revert previous revision in SVN

Tags: svn

I wonder how could I revert to a particular revision in repository, not in working copy?

Can i do it using svn user interface?  if so, how? it is easy to revert back to a previous version in working copy.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but probablt the best way to do it is via command line

```
svn up -r [revision_number]
```

you might want to google it I am sure there must be a lot of results of what you're looking for

---

Update

Somebody correct me if I'm wrong but I think you can't remove revisions that are already in SVN

Comment: i have got a few commits or revisions which I would like to remove or roll back from repository.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have modified a file a.sql and the committed revision is 100. Now you have identified that the file modification was not required. You cannot `uncommit` the revision 100 in SVN. [You cannot delete a revision in SVN]. Instead you can checkout the parent folder and do a reverse merge from revision 100 to 99.

From the working copy,

> svn merge -r 100:99 .

Now your working copy will look like as it was in revision 99. You need to commit the changes now, and the svn repository revision will become 101.

If you are using Tortoise-svn you may be interested in [this](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-howto-rollback.html).